# Replace all occurances of a question mark on the page with a <span> using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I want to search all the text on the page for a question mark. Then I would like to replace each question mark with a  tag. I already tried this but it didn't work.

```
var myStr = '?';

myStr.replace(/\?/g, '<span class="questionMarkSwitch">?</span>');
```

Please help me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You example actually works, you just didn't save what the `replace` method returned. So this should work:

```js
var myStr = '?';
myStr = myStr.replace(/\?/g, '<span class="questionMarkSwitch">?</span>');
    
console.log(myStr);
```

I hope I understood you right.

Comment: Thank you for your help! That didn't work either. Not sure what happened but I found another way to go about it. I will post as an answer

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to use regex is to use split and replace, could be more performatic for long strings and works for all ocurrences of the search string not only for the first one:

```
var myStr = myStr.split('?').join('<span class="questionMarkSwitch">?</span>');
```

Answer (score 0):

This actually worked for me.

```
$('body :not(script)').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType === 3;
}).replaceWith(function() {
    return this.nodeValue.replace(/\?/g,'<span class = "questionMarkSwitch">?</span>');
});
```